# Display lyrics while playing song in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I made audio player in xamarin forms(PCL) as Follows:

Audio.xaml(PCL):

```
          <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="CPL.pages.audio">
        <ContentPage.Content>
         <StackLayout>
           <ListView x:Name="lstSongsList" ItemSelected="lstSongsList_ItemSelected">
               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                  <ViewCell>
                      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label x:Name="lblFileName" Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                        <Label x:Name="lblLength" Text="{Binding Length}"></Label>
                      </StackLayout>
                  </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
               </ListView.ItemTemplate>
           </ListView>
         </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
      </ContentPage>
```

Audio.xaml.cs(PCL):

```
     private void lstSongsList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selected = (Entity.File)e.SelectedItem;
        try
        {
            if(selected != null)
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new player(selected));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Player.xaml.cs(PCL):

```cs
public player(Entity.File entity)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _file = entity;
    DependencyService.Get<iFile>().PlayFile(entity.FullPath);
}
```

Files.cs(Android):

```cs
public bool PlayFile(string filePath)
{
    if(currentFile != filePath)
    {
        if (_mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            _mediaPlayer.Stop();
        }
        _mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create(global::Android.App.Application.Context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(filePath));
        _mediaPlayer.Start();
        var file = rootDirectory.GetFiles(".lrc", SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault();
        _mediaPlayer.AddTimedTextSource(file.FullName, "application/octet-stream");
        _mediaPlayer.SetVolume(100, 100);
        currentFile = filePath;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It works fine in play and pause but I am unable to display lyrics which is attached in addtimedTextSource file. I have to display lyrics while play the song.

Anyone have idea about displaying lyrics of audio in xamarin forms?

Comment: How you're making your screen? Where are you binding the lyrics?

Comment: I have made one audio.xaml screen for listing songs and it redirects to this player.xaml page when we click on any song of that list

Comment: Please add your xaml file

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have add xaml file and code behind